# Problema con laravel y faker

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo una migración. De esta manera `php artisan migrate: fresh --seed` ¿Me podrían ayudar, por favor?

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
InvalidArgumentException  : Start date must be anterior to end date.

  at C:\miapp\vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Provider\DateTime.php:128
    124|         $startTimestamp = $startDate instanceof \DateTime ? $startDate->getTimestamp() : strtotime($startDate);
    125|         $endTimestamp = static::getMaxTimestamp($endDate);
    126|
    127|         if ($startTimestamp > $endTimestamp) {
  > 128|             throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Start date must be anterior to end date.');
    129|         }
    130|
    131|         $timestamp = mt_rand($startTimestamp, $endTimestamp);
    132|

  Exception trace:

  1   Faker\Provider\DateTime::dateTimeBetween("now", "2018-11-29")
      C:\miapp\vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Generator.php:222

  2   call_user_func_array()
      C:\miapp\vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Generator.php:222
```

Comment: Dice que la fecha de inicio debe ser anterior a la de finalización, revisa las fechas.

Comment: Veo que estás usando mt_rand, allí puede estar el problema, que aleatoriamente está generando fechas y para ellos debes colocarle condiciones para que no suceda eso (Que la fecha de inicio sea menor a la de finalización

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, no estoy migrando ninguna fecha y se supone que los timestamp se crean automáticamente, sin embargo añadí en el factory 'created_at'            => $faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-30 years', $endDate = 'now') y sigue el problema

Comment: Revisa bien, en esta línea pareciera que estás trabajando con fechas:  $timestamp = mt_rand($startTimestamp, $endTimestamp);

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta, al final me toco volver a hacer un nuevo proyecto, menos mal no había avanzado mucho así que no perdí mucho trabajo, pero te agradezco tu ayuda